# IIS 7.5 logging, how do I include milliseconds in the time field?

Tags: logging, iis-7.5, iis

Currently, my IIS log looks like this (using W3C logging):

```
2012-02-15 00:31:50 W3SVC1 ...
```

Is there a way to include milliseconds, such as:

```
2012-02-15 00:31:50.123 W3SVC1 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no problem with an alternative logging provider, simply download, install, enable and configure the [Advanced Logging extension](http://www.iis.net/download/AdvancedLogging) to IIS 7 and 7.5

The standard definition of the UTC time stamp, is in the format: `HH:MM:SS.sss` just as you want.

For more information on the Advanced Logging feature and how to configure it, read [this blog post](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis---custom-logging/)

---

With the built-in W3C extended log format: **No!**

Though I can't possibly know that. The only thing I know, is that [the official W3C standard draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html) specifies that the *time* field is **NOT** of the same type as the *time-taken* field (which does include milliseconds).

They are of the types `<time>` and `<fixed>`, respectively, and I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft hardcoded the formats, since the draft allows for some freedom to choose how accurate an implementation should be (just HH:MM would be considered a valid `<time>` format)

Comment: I'll give you a +1 but let's not focus on W3C, I'd gladly change to a different IIS logging format if it offered better logging.

Comment: I see, thought you were asking specifically about W3C logging in IIS, updated the answer

Comment: Unfortunately the 2 year old bug mentioned in http://forums.iis.net/t/1169433.aspx means I can't use Advanced Logging.

Comment: That's a bummer... Since you haven't revealed the motif behind your urge to log the timestamp in milliseconds and include custom fields, but you might want to look into [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)