# How to capture milliseconds in IIS 10 log files?

Tags: iis

I have enabled IIS logging to capture a bunch of fields in Windows server 2016 with IIS 10. Here is the screen shot of the fields I have selected.

[image]

I could see that log files are getting generated and log entries are written for all the http traffic. The Time field is only displaying hour, minute and seconds in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), at which the request occurred.

Here is an example of the log entry where Time filed is just displaying 15:07:37 (HH:mm:ss).

> 2017-11-30 15:07:37 15.79.72.01 POST /IntegrationService/api/products/
>   - 80 ADX/userxyz 132.40.11.16 - - 200 0 0 62

How can I capture milliseconds part of the time field? 
I looked at the documentation from Microsoft but I don't see any details around it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis

I have asked this question in stack overflow, but I thought this might be the correct place for it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579519/how-to-capture-milliseconds-in-iis-10-log-files

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/360194/iis-7-5-logging-how-do-i-include-milliseconds-in-the-time-field

Comment: Advanced logging extension says that it for is 7, 7.5 and 8. It does not say that it is also for IIS 10, I looked into and backed off, wondering if I should just give it a try

Comment: The Advanced Logging extension does not work on IIS 10. I have not found a solution to allow IIS 10 to log in milliseconds other than to frontend to site through something like nginx that does support robust logging.